# Best practice for accessing build context from multiple classes for app localization in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I have got a class that needs to generate some words and sentences using the localized app resources. I access them using `AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld`. The class that needs to access these localized resources is initialized by a class which is initialized by another class with is initialized by a database helper class with is initialized by an actual widget. The problem is that only the widget has the `BuildContext` I need in my generating words class. Is it best practice to just pass the build context through all the constructors or methods of the different classes or is there a better way? Any advice would be highly apriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter intl for internationalization like it shows on [`Localizations in Flutter`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) .
It is better to use context when available.Here's how you'd do it.

```dart
AppLocalization.of(context).title
or
Applocalization.current.title 
//In case buildcontext is not available.
```

Here is a reference to the implementation on medium blog.
[Flutter Localization](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2)

Alternatively, I would suggest you to check out VSCode extension (if you use vscode) for `Flutter intl` extension and follow the steps on the extension itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to be exactly what I am searching for. But I have not found a way to implement it on the site you linked. Never is the word current used in the document and it is also never used in the example projects given. Can you please add a link to a resource so I can see how to implement it in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer. I personally recommend using Flutter intl extension because it generates the translation file on saving after you add the key in individual arb file.